# Data Factory Data Flow (REST to Flatten to Delta) - dynamic Flatten

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pretty simple Data Factory Mapping Data Flow:

- my source is a REST API, but for all intents and purposes you can imagine is a JSON file source
- the source JSON has an OData structure similar to this:

> ```
> {
>         "@odata.context": "https://link/api/v1/$metadata#Endpoint1",
>         "value": [
>             {
>                 "Id": 0,
>                 "Name": "Email"
>             },
>             {
>                 "Id": 1,
>                 "Name": "SMS"
>             },
>             {
>                 "Id": 2,
>                 "Name": "Carrier Pigeon"
>             }
>         ]
> }
> ```

- the Flatten hierarchy should dynamically unroll by "body.value" and retrieve all underlying nodes as new columns - in above example the columns sent to the sink should be [Id, Name]
  the Flatten is configed as below:
  [image: Pipeline with Flatten configuration displayed]
- the Sink is a Delta table in ADLSgen2, with Merge schema enabled:
  [image: Sink]
- the above Data Flow has the API endpoint as a parameter and is executed in a Foreach activity for a list of endpoints:
  [image: Pipeline with Foreach]
- Foreach configuration:
  [image: Foreach configuration]

The issue is that the metadata (columns names and data types) from the initial Data Flow development - where I used an API endpoint for the Projection schema - is kept and propagated in other endpoints execution.

When it worked, I realized that the endpoint was loaded, but with all the columns from the "model" endpoint with "None" values on the columns not existing in the current endpoint.
This is an example where CreationDate was a common field, Disabled existed only in the current endpoint and all the rest were from the "model" endpoint:
[image: columns in sink]

Another example, when loading another endpoint that had an Id column with a different data type I had a data type clash error:

> Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'Id' and 'Id'. Failed to merge incompatible data types StringType and ShortType;;","Details":"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'Id' and 'Id'. Failed to merge incompatible data types StringType and ShortType

I tried to create a Data Flow from scratch, without importing the schema in the Source Projection, but the the Flatten transform returned an error - I used a "body.value" as expression in Flatten - and I did not have the option of "Hierarchy level" in the Rule-based mapping:

> Operation on target Data flow1 failed: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at FoldDown 'Flatten1'(Line 14/Col 8): unrollby should reference a array or map column","Details":""}

"body.value" expression in Flatten:
[image: Flatten manual unroll by]

If someone successfully used Flatten in this dynamic manner, please let me know how you did - I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My solution is here:

- I added Derived Column with new column `tempArray` with value `array("1")` before Flatten.
- In Flatten then just unroll by `tempArray` and in Hierarchy level use `body.value`.

It works like a charm.